# NetSuite SOAP, how do I get a list of the Service Sale Items?

Tags: .net, soap, netsuite

I need to get all the Service Sale Items from inventory, using the NetSuite SOAP services in .NET Framework.  I can Add/Update Sale Orders, search for a specific Job/Item and other functions.  But I am struggling on just getting all the Service Sale Items in Inventory.

Here is the code I am running, and the error I receive is = The field type's enum value  is invalid for this search.

```
    Public Shared Function GetInventoryItems() As String
        Try
            Dim itm As New ItemSearch
            Dim itmBasic As New ItemSearchBasic
            Dim itmAdv As New ItemSearchAdvanced

            Client.SetPreferences()
            Client.SetSearchPreferences(False, True)

            Dim fld As New SearchEnumMultiSelectField
            fld.operator = SearchEnumMultiSelectFieldOperator.anyOf
            fld.operatorSpecified = True
            fld.searchValue = {"serviceSaleItem"}
            itmBasic.type = fld

            itm.basic = itmBasic
            itmAdv.criteria = itm
            Dim res As SearchResult = Client.Service.search(itmAdv)
            Return res.recordList.ToString
        Catch ex As Exception
            Return "ERROR : " & ex.Message
        End Try
    End Function

    Public Sub SetPreferences()
        Prefs = New Preferences()
        _service.preferences = Prefs
        SearchPreferences = New SearchPreferences()
        _service.searchPreferences = SearchPreferences
        Prefs.warningAsErrorSpecified = True
        Prefs.warningAsError = False
        Prefs.ignoreReadOnlyFieldsSpecified = True
        Prefs.ignoreReadOnlyFields = True
        SearchPreferences.pageSize = PageSize
        SearchPreferences.pageSizeSpecified = True
        SearchPreferences.bodyFieldsOnly = True
        _service.tokenPassport = CreateTokenPassport()
    End Sub

    Public Sub SetSearchPreferences(ByVal bodyFieldsOnly As Boolean, ByVal returnColumns As Boolean)
        _service.searchPreferences.bodyFieldsOnly = bodyFieldsOnly
        _service.searchPreferences.returnSearchColumns = returnColumns
    End Sub
```